# The duration of audio from list of audio urls is not properly loading in table view

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, duration, avplayeritem

```
if let url = URL(string: url) {
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async{
                    let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
                        let duration = Double(item.asset.duration.value) / Double(item.asset.duration.timescale)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            cell.label.text = "\(duration)"
                        }
                }
            }
```

I am listing a list of audio files.I have to calculate the duration of each audio and show as well.Above is the code which i have used.The durations are not properly showing when the table view is scrolled.I am able to calculate the duration using this code . But the problem is, the durations are not listed properly when scrolling the list.The durations which i have calculated are interchanged while scrolling.

Comment: "The durations are not properly showing" -- what does this mean? Not showing at all? Formatted incorrectly? What are you seeing vs. what do you expect?

Comment: I have editted the question . Sorry for the confusion .

Comment: Sounds like a cell reuse problem, but you'll need to provide more details than "durations are not listed properly when scrolling the list".

Comment: yes, it seems like cell reuse issue.How to solve it?the durations which i got after calculation are automatically interchanged while scrolling.